# JavaScript set bits from the left

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation

I have a number, for example `128`. Its bit representation is `10000000`.
I want to set the 3rd bit from the left to have `10100000` (`160`).

I thought that I could do this with:

```
var foo = 128;
foo = foo | 1 << 2;
```

But this gives me `132` or `10000100`. It set the 3rd *from the right*!
How to set it from the left **to 0 or to 1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
var foo = 128;
foo = foo | foo >> 2
```

But what if you want to turn it on and off?

```
var foo = 128;
var mask = foo >> 2;

// Flick the bit on
foo = foo | mask;
// foo now equals 160

// Set the bit back to 0
foo = foo & ~mask;
// foo equals 128 again
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. `>>` will do work from right side shifting

```
var foo = 128;
foo = foo | foo >> 2;
```

[**Refrence for Bitwise operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: I just typed this into node.js. `1 >> 2` returned 0. `128 | 1 >> 2` returned 128.

Comment: Its stays 128: https://jsfiddle.net/75k1bxzt/1/ Andrew solution works by setting it to 1, but how can I set the 3rd bit back to 0?

Comment: @pistacchio - I've modified my answer to setting  it back to 0 again

Answer (score 1):

```js
function transformBits(bits, order, target) {
  var bitStr = bits
    .toString(2)
    .split('')
    .map(function(value, index) { 
      return index == (order - 1) ? target : value; 
    })
    .join('');

  return parseInt(bitStr, 2);
}

document.writeln(transformBits(128, 3, 1));
document.writeln(transformBits(128, 3, 0));
```